# How to cast a IncomingWebRequestContext to HttpRequestMessage type and vice versa

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api2

I have a class method that is used with WCF Web Services that expects and IncomingWebRequestContext parameter and returns an OutgoingWebResponseContext type parameter.  I am using a WEB API application that will use this class method but my parameters are of type HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage.
Not sure how I can cast my request and responses to fit the methods appropriately. Is it possible?
e.g.

```
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.ServiceModel;

    public OutgoingWebResponseContext myServiceMethod(IncomingWebRequestcontext webRequest)
{ ..... 
OutgoingWebResponseContext webResponse new OutgoingWebResponseContext ();  return webResponse 
}

    //my webApi does this...
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;

    public class apicontroller{
    public myAPImethod(){
    var myApiRequest = Request;
    HttpWebResponseMessage myApiResponse = new HttpWebResponseMessage();
    myApiResponse = myServiceMethod(myApiRequest);
    }
```

Perhaps I should clarify.  I have a method that authenticates a headertoken of a WCF or WEBAPI.  It is a token we generate and validate through our own procedure. The method is defined in a class not an apicontroller just a class. I want to call this authenticate method from my apicontroller and send it my request The method will extract the token from header analyze it will return a response. there could be multiple different responses e.g. internal error, unauthorized etc, if it is successful it will then call the get data from my business logic class (non-apicontroller) which will then return the data and also set response status and description.  The current method I already have that authenticates the token is expecting wcf params. (this method will be shared with a WCF project that passes the WCF request param)  What I did was I created another method that expects Web API params within the same class.  but now I'm not sure how to set the WEB API responses. I need the status and description. @JotaBe

Answer (score 0):

This doesn' look like a good idea. I wouldn't reuse a WCF method. I'd do in the following way instead:

- in your WCF service, extract the business logic to a different class. Modify it so that your WCF context only takes care of messaging, but not of doing anything else. That task is for the BL class, so you'll have

  - a WCF service that depends on a BL class
  - a BL class which "does the hard work"
- in your Web API simply use the new BL class

*Hopefully, you already have this BL class*

Your idea doesn't look reasonable because both WCF and Web API depend on context to get executed, and sooner or later you'll have trouble if you try to reuse WCF from inside Web API, because you cannot provide that context.

Comment: Yes, I do have that format, however this is a class method that is shared with all the WCF calls (and now I'm trying to create an API app that uses it also) that gets the token from the header and authenticates it first.  Thus the reason why I need to pass the request and the response so I can either set it to pass or fail. After that the BL classes are used to get the data and those are separate.

Comment: You should not authenticate inside the Web API actions. You should authenticate in previous steps. You can implement a filter attribute for it (although there are many other options). You can acces the header from the authentication filter, and validate it. Hopefully the validation logic is also in an external class, and not hard-coded inside the WCF methods. If not, extract the validation class from there. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters There are also authorization filters in Web API, which run after the authentication ones.